# what is the reason behind vector's push_back error

Tags: c++

I have a simple c++ std::vector and inside it, i am storing threads as shown below. Can you please explain why the line with comment "does not compile" shows error during compilation? And why the line with comment "compiles" work?

```
#include<thread>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
void abc() {}
int main()
{
   vector<thread> workers;
   workers.push_back(thread(abc)); // compiles
   thread t(abc);
   workers.push_back(t); // does not compile

   return 0;
 }
```

UPDATE: i am using g++ 4.4.6 on linux. Below is the error

```
[jim@cola c++]$ g++ -std=c++0x -pthread -g -Wall t.cpp -o t
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:34,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/string:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/iostream:40,
                 from t.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread: In member function ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Tp*, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::thread]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:737:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::thread, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]’
t.cpp:29:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread:122: error: deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:105: error: used here
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/vector:69,
                 from t.cpp:4:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = const std::thread&, _Tp = std::thread, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:741:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::thread, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]’
t.cpp:29:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/thread:122: error: deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/vector.tcc:314: error: used here
```

Comment: When asking about compilation/linker errors, you *need* to post the *entire, unedited* error message.

Comment: It would also help if you posted a _compilable_ example. I know what `std::vector` is, but not what just plain `vector` is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg fixed it by using the namespace std

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're getting the error because `std::thread` is *noncopyable,* and you're trying to insert a copy of `t` into the vector.

The only way you could make this work would be to do:

```
workers.push_back(std::move(t));
```

However, this would mean that after you do that, `t` no longer represents a thread (the thread it represented was moved into the vector).

Comment: how can i insert a reference ?

Comment: Even if he weren't inserting a copy (i.e. emplacing), `std::vector` still requires the ability to reallocate its memory block, which requires moving or copying.

Comment: @Potatoswatter However, `std::thread` is movable, so it can be inserted into a `std::vector` just fine.

Comment: @Potatoswatter the push_back requires const reference. Is there a way i can provide reference to the stack variable t?

Comment: @Jimm You don't have to, the stack variable is simply passed by reference. However, note that as I said in my answer, `push_back()` tries to place a copy of its argument into the vector. This fails, because you can't copy `std::thread` objects.

Comment: @Angew ah didn't realize that. Often things that represent operating system resources aren't movable.

Comment: @Angew Do you know where the include thread.h can be found on linux. I would like to read the code for non copyable

Comment: @Jimm It's `thread`, not `thread.h`. And you should be able to see include file paths by adding `-H` to your gcc command line. Also, it's made noncopyable by declaring a deleted copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Angew why does workers.push_back(thread t(abc)) works? even in this case, a copy would be made

Comment: @Jimm `thread t(abc)` creates a temporary (in standardese, an **xvalue**). xvalues can bind to rvalue references, that is, they can implicitly be moved from. This means the code invokes the overload `push_back(T&&)`, not `push_back(const T&)`.

Comment: @Angew I'm pretty sure a temporary is a prvalue.

Comment: @sftrabbit You're correct, of course. I wish editing comments had no time limit.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `std::thread` has a move constructor, but doesn't have a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaner and faster solution that requires neither copying nor moving:

```
workers.emplace_back(abc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::thread` is not **copyable**, you could move it to vector though:

```
   thread t(abc);
   workers.push_back(std::move(t));
```

Better solution is to store smart pointer in vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> workers;
```

Because when work with lambda, there is no way to capture a move only type, a workaround is to  store a move-only type in `std::shared_ptr<std::thread>`.

Comment: Would you elaborate why you consider dynamic allocation better in this case?

Comment: I still don't quite understand. What's wrong with [this lambda](http://ideone.com/jtS60U)?